# Can the "drag to applications" of a mounted DMG volume be done in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, mount, dmg

Attempting to automatically install a .DMG downloaded(of Docker), so that the host has access to `docker run` etc. in Terminal.

I can attach the volume with no issue with:

`curl -O https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg > ./Docker.dmg`

And then mount it:

`hdiutil attach Docker.dmg`

How do I step further from here and actually mock the "drag and drop to Applications" that will then be prompted to the user?

To my knowledge there is no .pkg inside this image. So I can't use the related question's answers(that were dubded as duplicate before, this question is more precise.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command once the .dmg is open to copy the app:

```
 cp -R /Volumes/Docker/Docker.app /Applications
```

The user will get the usual pop-up security window when the app is first run:

[image]

You can further automate the process by ejecting the disk image:

```
 diskutil unmount /Volumes/Docker
```

Then opening the app to get the security warning:

```
 open /Applications/Docker.app
```

Comment: I'll give this a go and test it on a fresh OSX with no Docker. Will be interesting to see if it works :P I've been using `hdiutil` to mount and unmount, should one use `diskutil`instead?

Comment: `hdiutil` will work just as well as `diskutil`, I think.